# Split pandas column of list stored as string to multiple rows (literal_eval error)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column of list stored as string. The lists have varying sizes. I want to split the items in lists to multiple rows

```
df['urls']
0    '[http://sth/sth]'
1    '[http://sth.COM, https://twitter.com/i/etc]'
2    '[]'
```

Tried using `literal_eval()` function:

```
df['urls'] = df['urls'].map(lambda x: literal_eval(x))
```

but got the following error:

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
[http://sth/sth]
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep only the url as text, you can use `strip()` and then `split()`:

```
s = '[http://sth.COM, https://twitter.com/i/etc]'
s = s.strip('[]') # this will remove the [] at the beginning and ending of the string.
urls = s.split(',') # this will separate both urls, returning a list of strings. ['http://sth.COM', ' https://twitter.com/i/etc']
```

You can do the stripping part using slices too:

```
s = '[http://sth.COM, https://twitter.com/i/etc]'
s = s[1:-1] # this will keep everything except first and last characters, in this case [ and ].
urls = s.split(',') # this will separate both urls, returning a list of strings. ['http://sth.COM', ' https://twitter.com/i/etc']
```

I hope it helps!